# How to configure front proxy in Play

Tags: proxy, playframework-2.0, ejabberd

I am trying to make a /http-bind/ call from my browser client but my XMPP server is in different domain and I am using play as a web server. I am facing CORS issue. Is it possible to have some route or proxy which I can configure within play to call the XMPP server. I don't want to use nginx or apache proxy(or any external proxy server). 
I just wanted to know if there is some front proxy kind of feature available in Play which I can use in the given scenario.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: So you want that play works as a proxy between your client and XMPP server?

Comment: yes, exactly....I don't want to use 3rd party proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, yes you can do this.

Check out [Play WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/JavaWS). Just have a route in your Play server, where the Play code for the route calls out to your XMPP server, and return the response.